# Play video of any format in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I play a video of any format (eg:Mpeg etc) in c#.net ? Thanks

Comment: How much research have you put into this? Do you want to embed it into a webpage?

Comment: Yea, I want to play a video file in asp.net page.

Comment: I want to embed it in a web page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yea, I want to play a video file in asp.net page.

OK, there are two parts to this problem; you need to have:

1. Something which can play videos in a browser.
2. A way of getting the video to the browser.

At the time of writing, your basic options for #1 are - HTML5, Flash, or Silverlight.  In the near future, HTML5 will probably be the simplest to use, but right now some browsers will not be able to show an HTML5 video.  You are left with Flash or Silverlight, and there are many tutorials out there on how to achieve this (e.g. [this one](http://soulsolutions.com.au/Articles/YourvideotoSilverlightStreaming101.aspx)).  Once you have decided on what technology to use, streaming the video to it should be relatively simple, you could test it by simply hosting a static video in IIS for starters.

Answer (score 1):

You can play videos using DirectShow.

You can handle directshow direclty. Example page: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directshowmediaplayer.aspx

Or using a thirdparty library to help: http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/